# Limit of form $ \frac{a^{x} - 1} {x} $ as $ x \to 0 $

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have this question where the part that I cannot understand what to do and how to start the problem. The answer options are given in the form of ln. But, the only logarithmic property of limits I know so far is:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)} {x} = 1 
$$

But in this case, the full question is:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{3 ^{x} - 5^{x} }{x} $$

So, is it just a matter of some manipulation of the previous known property, or is there some special theory required for me to cover?
I am actually new to calculus and we didn't cover the L' Hopital's rule and other things, so a solution or hint without using that would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the answer to the question in the title? You can actually use that to answer the full question, with a little sneakiness.

Comment: Actually that was the manipulation shown in a hint in the solution, and I got it to the part where we split the fraction by adding and subtracting 1 in the numerator as:
$ \frac{3^{x} - 1} {x} - \frac{5^{x} -1} {x} $
But then after this they directly converted it to a logarithmic limit as ln 3 - ln 5 and the final answer was ln(3/5)

Comment: The exact conversion wasn't taught to us yet, as the only thing we learned which related limits to logarithms was the property i mentioned above.
So, yeah I don't actually know the answer to that question.. Was hoping someone could provide hints to the derivation if its easy to comprehend :)

Comment: What is the *definition* of the derivative of $f(x)=a^x$ at $x=0$? Then, what is the *value* of the derivative of $f(x)=a^x$ at $x=0$?

Comment: Ah I see, so we get  the value as $ f(0) = a ^ 0 = 1 $ so the derivative is $ ln(a) $ at x = 0  at $ x = 0 $ and the definition as $ f'(x) = a^x ln(a) $ ?

Comment: Ok I understood it now! Thanks for your valuable help!
So the answer becomes:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \: {3^x ln(3)} - {5^x ln(5)} $$
and then when x = 0 is substituted, $ ln (3/5) $
So i got the proof for the general form of the limit as well, answering the question in the title :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\ln a$$
the proof of which is [here](https://planetmath.org/limitofdisplaystylefracax1xasxapproaches0).

So, for your question,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3^x-5^x}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(3^x-1)-(5^x-1)}{x}=\ln 3-\ln 5$$
This completes the answer.

Comment: I don't understand your last line. Did you mean $3^x-1...$?

Comment: @lonestudent Sorry, I did the edit. Thanks for pointing it out. Maybe I went crazy when typing that out :):):)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

we can do the following:

Take $t=a^x-1 \longrightarrow x=\log_{a}(t+1)=(\log{a})^{-1}\log(t+1)$.

And note that $t\to0$ as $x\to0$

Then, we want to calculate

$$\log{a}\cdot\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t}{log(t+1)}$$
Which you already now that is equal to $\log{a}\cdot1$ but can be calculate by using Taylor expansion is you don't want to use Lhopital.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't know what the Taylor expansion exactly is right now, I'm still in an introductory calculus stage (we didn't learn anything yet except basic limit definitions), but your answer and help were appreciated :)